# Copy a row and then insert a new row above it

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have a macro filled workbook that has worked fine for months and now when the user uses one macro I get the error (excel cannot complete this task with available resources). Once I exit out of the error I get the error (Run-time error '1004': Insert method of range class failed)

One more thing I should add. Before I received this error another user was given the error (there isn't enough memory to complete this action. Try using less data or closing other applications. to Increase memory availability, consider....)

The basis of the macro is to insert a row above row 6. I looked online but could not find a solution that helped. I don't think it's the code causing the problem because I am unable to insert a row without the use of macros.

```
Sub NewData()

    Worksheets("Log").Rows(6).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

    Application.Worksheets("Log").Range("N6").Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your range and then insert a row above it using `offset(-1,0)`. Try something like this:

```
Sub insertaboverow()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("N6")

    If Not rng.Cells(1, 1) Is Nothing Then
        rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Rows.Insert   
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I receive the run-time error '1004' insert method of Range class failed. I am unable to insert my own row without the use of a macro.

Comment: If I try to delete the row outside of the macro I get the Large Operation warning. "the operation you are about to perform affects a large number of cells and may take a significant amount of time to complete.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe [This will help](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cannot-insert-new-row-in-excel/7c6ae7f3-a844-4b14-abf4-31261ad2ebab).